# grails Command Object deep data binding

Tags: grails

I have two domain objects and one command that looks something like

```
class Vendor {
    String phoneNumber

    public String toString() {
        """[phoneNumber: "${phoneNumber ?: ''}"]"""
    }
}

class Product {
    String productNumber
    Vendor vendor

    public String toString() {
        """[productNumber: "${productNumber ?: ''}", vendor: "${vendor}"]"""
    }
}

class SaveProductCommand {
    Product product
}
```

I have a form that looks something like:

```
<g:formRemote>
    <input type="text" name="product.productNumber" value="12345" />
    <input type="text" name="product.vendor.phoneNumber" value="18005551212" />
</g:formRemote>
```

My controller call looks something like:

```
def save(SaveProductCommand cmd) {
    // do stuff
}
```

When I examine the product I see something like:

```
[productNumber: "12345", vendor: "null"]
```

Is grails able to do data binding over multiple levels? If so, can anyone see what I am doing wrong? If not, can anyone offer a work-around?

Comment: Given just the code you show there, that doesn't make sense.  There must be something else in the mix that is problematic.  You might find something interesting if you interrogate `cmd.errors` and `cmd.product.errors`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, command object binding works with arbitrarily deep nested paths.  You may have a typo or something else in your app that is problematic, but the binder does support what you are talking about.

See the sample app at https://github.com/jeffbrown/simplebinding.  If you submit the form on the default index page you will see that both properties are bound properly.